# Redirecting stdout of a child process

Tags: python, unix, pipe, stdout

I am trying to create a program which forks a child process and then monitors its stdout. My understanding is that this should be achievable by creating a set of pipe fds and then setting the write end of the pipe to STDOUT in the child using dup. The code below attempts to do this

```
import os
import sys
import time
pid = os.fork()
pr, pw = os.pipe()

if pid == 0: #Inside child
    os.close(pr)
    os.dup2(pw, sys.stdout.fileno())
    print("Inside the child")
    exit(1)

print("Inside parent, waiting for child output..")
result = os.read(pr, 1024)
print(result)
```

But yields the 'broken pipe' error below.

```
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/master.py", line 14, in <module>
  result = os.read(pr, 1024)
```

I have looked at a few examples but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. The error suggests that the read end of the pipe is prematurely closed but this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: You've got _two_ disparate pipes (i.e. parent and child have different ones). Do the `pipe` _before_ the `fork` to have a single shared pipe

Comment: Doh! Well this is embarrassing...

Comment: any reasons why you're using low level API like `os.fork` instead of higher level APIs like `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`?